# How to sort data in android

Tags: java, android

I have a custom adapter class from which I get a bulk load of data. Each of the data is added to a custom cell. Each cell has a title, description, price and creation date. When clicked on a spinner view for sorting, it should sort the data accordingly. The data is received from web services. How can I go about in doing this?
Thanks.

Comment: you have to sort data in the List that you are passing to Adapter

Comment: you can use Collection.sort() method. Example at : http://www.limbaniandroid.com/2013/01/sorting-arraylist-string-arraylist-and.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following way.

Let say you have "CustomData" class and its array then you can use it by following way.

```
Collections.sort(customList, new Comparator<CustomData>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(CustomData object1, CustomData object2) {
        return object1.getTitle().compareTo(object2.getTitle());
    }
});
```

Here, i have sorted list by using *Title* field. You can use as per your requirement.

To display sorted data, after getting your data from web service either you can sort there or you can sort data before setting adapter to your spinner.